# Create an html menu with js for responsive site

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I have an existing website with a nice responsive menu and I want to copy this menu to a new website.

The problem is that the structure of the menu of the new website is quite complicated and I am having a trouble to apply the css and js of the old website.

My question is: On my new website, from the existing menu can I create a new one with javascript (on page load) to match the structure of the old one and then I can import my css & js ? and is it bad for performance or against the best practices?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey! The question is not very clear, can you please explain what you have in mind when you mention "matching the structure of the old one and then importing my css & js"?

Ultimately I think you should shoot to understand how the responsive menu works and then you'll be able to keep the code as simple as possible. I know it's difficult sometimes to understand someone else's code but I know you can do it! Try to look for documentation on it by taking looking at the javascript files to see if there is a comment on the top about the name of the script so you can search for documentation on it.

Comment: I want to know if I insert a new html menu (on document ready for example) : I will take the existing menu and build a simple one, as I said the existing structure is complicated (I have several divs inside li ) and I want to know if I do this it will cause performance issue ...

Comment: Still confused, I'm sorry I don't think I can help you on this one :(

Comment: I want to do something like this:
$(document).ready(function(){
 if (mobile) {
  //hide the existing menu and
  //construct a new menu from the existing one.
  //insert the new menu
  var newMenu = '<ul class="menu">'>
  newMenu += '<li class="menu-level1">';
  ...
  $('nav').append(newMenu);
 } else{
  //display the existing menu and remove the mobile menu
 }
});

I hope I am clear this time :)